# Instagram get images

Tags: android, flutter, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am writing a test application for android in flutter and what I want to do is show my Instagram images in my app.
I don't want the users of my application to enter their Instagram Id and authorize and see their images. I want to display my Instagram account images only. basically using my app as a gallery.

I tried to search and every tutorial and article that I found talked about how to integrate Instagram display API and authorization. I don't want this. I just want to generate some sort of one-time key and secret to my profile and add it in my app's source code to get images from my own account. does anyone know how to achieve this?
also if there is any flutter library that does this it would be even better.
thanks.

Comment: That's impossible. Instagram changes authorization tokens regularly.

Comment: did you later get it done?

Comment: Nope unfortunately